# Index or mapping according to given variable in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question related to python
Suppose I have two variables, one with numbers ( numeric value) and other with strings( Alphabets, can be any)
Numberic variable have integers while string variable have alphabets like ABCGHGAA etc.

```
Numberic_variable = 23,28,34,26,45,67
string_variable = ATGCTC

I want to index/map my alphabets/strings as following corresponding to the numeric value like below:
23       28      34     26      45      67
A        T        G      C      T       C
```

I want to use this mapping in order to compare my values from another file lets say in other text file I have position 34 and in my above variable I also have position 34 now I want to see if the same alphabet is present on both positions are not.
Please help me in understanding this concept.
How would we code this in Python, I have tried a lot but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip()` and assign it to a `dict`.

```
Numberic_variable = [23,28,34,26,45,67]
string_variable = 'ATGCTC'

result = dict(zip(Numberic_variable, string_variable))

#{23: 'A', 28: 'T', 34: 'G', 26: 'C', 45: 'T', 67: 'C'}

print(result[23])
#'A'
```

You could also `zip` it to other formats such as

**List**

```
list(zip(Numberic_variable, string_variable))
#[(23, 'A'), (28, 'T'), (34, 'G'), (26, 'C'), (45, 'T'), (67, 'C')]
```

**Tuple**

```
tuple(zip(Numberic_variable, string_variable))
#((23, 'A'), (28, 'T'), (34, 'G'), (26, 'C'), (45, 'T'), (67, 'C'))
```

Comment: WIth above command it gives following error in my data

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9349b358a22c> in <module>
      2 string_variable = read.seq
      3 # list(zip(Numberic_variable, string_variable))
----> 4 result = dict(zip(Numberic_variable, string_variable))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
This is the error